# Was genau ist ein Strom (Gewässer)?

Tags: meaning

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Difference between “Fluss” and “Strom”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27542)*

Bis heute habe ich nur *Fluss* gekannt. Aber jetzt kenne ich auch das Wort *Strom* für einen langen Fluss. Mir stellt sich folgende Frage: Ist die Bedeutung so unterschiedlich?

[Die Wikipedia-Seite über *Strom*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strom_%28Gew%C3%A4sser%29) führt eine Liste von Flüssen auf, die Strom genannt werden können. Aber der Brahmaputra ist nicht dabei. Soweit ich weiß, ist der Brahmaputra noch länger als der Ganges! Im Vergleich zu beiden ist der Rhein, der als *Strom* bezeichnet wird, viel kürzer als beide.

Deshalb möchte ich nun wissen, was genau versteht man unter einem Strom?

Comment: Das [Gewässerdiagramm](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gewaesserdiagramm.svg) ist ganz nett. Genauer wird's nicht -- die Liste in dem Wikipedia Artikel ist ja auch nicht erschöpfend gemeint, denke ich mal.

Comment: Was ich über die Entstehung von Sprache weiß sind scharfe, quantitative Definitionen wie die zu Länge und Einzugsgebiet untypisch für einen alltagssprachlichen Begriff. Wieso sollte nicht Breite/Tiefe/Wasserdurchsatz den Strom ausmachen? Dagegen scheint das Münden ins Meer eher ein brauchbares Kriterium, auch wenn ich es bislang nicht kannte. Dass aber ein Strom kein Fluß ist, wie das Diagramm behauptet, halte ich für Quatsch.

Comment: Das halte ich eher für einen Designfehler als für einen Teil der Information. Man füge einen Knoten für "Fluss" ein und mache "kleiner Fluss" und "ab 10m" zu dessen Kindern und schon passt's.

Comment: Der Wikpedia-Artikel zu *Strom* listet doch den Brahmaputra, und zwar nicht erst seit heute. Die wissenschaftliche Definition im Wikipedia-Artikel ist eben nur eine solche und für gewisse Zwecke sicher sinvoll. Dem gängigen Wortgebrauch braucht sie dennoch nicht zu entsprechen. Man stelle sich einen hypothetischen Fluss in einer trockenen Gegend vor, der zwar die Kriterien (Einzugsgebiet, Länge, Meermündung) erfüllt, aber so stark von Verdunstung betroffen ist, dass er kaum mehr als ein Bach ist. Niemand würde diesen außerhalb des gewässerkundlichen Kontexts als *Strom* bezeichnen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ja, ich sehe ich jetzt. Ich schwöre aber, dass es war nicht da wann ich diese Frage gestellt hatte. Deswegen scheint es alle ziemlich sinnlos. :D

Comment: Der Brahmaputra ist seit dem 23. März 2008 in der Liste. http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Strom_%28Gew%C3%A4sser%29&diff=44061372&oldid=40701797

Comment: Ja ist diese Frage meine größte Dummheit an dieser Seite. Glücklicherweise war die reale Frage sinnvoll.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das Wort "Strom" hat drei Aspekte:

1. Ein großer Fluss.
2. Ein wichtiger Fluss.
3. Teil der Folklore.

Der Rhein ist ein Strom nicht nur aufgrund seiner Wassermenge, sondern auch aufgrund seiner herausragenden historischen und bis heute andauernden Bedeutsamkeit als Grenze und Verkehrsweg und aufgrund der mit ihm verbundenen Folklore wie Lieder, Bücher, Filme, Sagen usw.

Damit ein Fluss "Strom" genannt wird, muss er in allen drei Bedeutungsdimensionen eine bestimmte (subjektive) Schwelle überschreiten: Er muss eine ungewöhnliche Länge oder Breite haben oder eine erstaunliche Wassermenge transportieren; er muss für Sprecher des Deutschen (denn Strom ist ein deutsches Wort!) eine wahrnehmbare herausragende wirtschaftliche, politische oder kulturelle Bedeutung besitzen; und er muss Teil der Folklore der Flussanrainer sein (und diese muss wiederum in Deutschland bekannt sein, wie die religiöse Bedeutung des Ganges oder der Mississippi durch die Erzählungen Mark Twains).

Flüsse, die in Deutschland kaum bekannt sind, wie der Brahmaputra, können in Deutschland auch nicht als Strom wahrgenommen werden oder nur von entsprechend informierten Personen.

Comment: +1 weil interessant trotz fehlender Literaturangaben (aber vielleicht kommen noch welche?)

Comment: Daraus folgt auch, dass die Menge der als Strom bezeichneten Flüsse von Mensch zu Mensch verschieden ist.

Comment: @Toscho Ganz genau. Google mal nach semantischer Unschärfe (fuzziness) oder Prototypikalität.

Comment: Vielleicht etwas aus dem Kontext, aber "Strom" hat auch auch den Aspekt "Elektrizität"...

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass *jeder* Strom alle drei Aspekte bedienen muss. Der erste Aspekt ist für mich der wichtigste, die weiteren Aspekte können auch etwas kleinere Flüsse zu Strömen machen, aber auch wenn ein Fluss keine folkloristische Bedeutung hat, kann er trotzdem ein Strom sein. Für mich persönlich ist der Größenaspekt herausragend, und deswegen würde ich sämtliche Flüsse unter großen Brücken der Transsibirischen als *Ströme* bezeichnen.

Comment: Das entspricht meiner Intuition, allerdings vermisse ich Quellen.

Answer (score 12):

Laut Herkunftswörterbuch aus dem Duden-Verlag bezeichnet *Strom* seit dem 19. Jahrhundert *große Flüsse*. Weitere charakterisierende Merkmale werden nicht genannt. Die ursprüngliche Bedeutung ist „das Fließen“ oder „fließendes Gewässer“.

Ein kurzer Blick in die Buchsuche von Google zeigt, dass sich im 18. und 19. Jahrhundert noch Bezeichnungen wie „Saalestrom“ oder „Muldestrom“ finden – Flüsse, die man heute nicht mehr als groß bezeichnen würde.

Answer (score 3):

Der Artikel [WP:Brahmaputra](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmaputra) bezeichnet ihn als Strom, was anhand der Kriterien im anderen Artikel ja auch gerechtfertigt ist. Dass er laut des "Strom"-Artikels nicht häufig als Strom genannt wird, ist wohl auf kulturelles Bias, d. h. seine geringere Bekanntheit, zurückzuführen.