# Difference between “Fluss” and “Strom”

Tags: difference

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Was genau ist ein Strom (Gewässer)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6381)*

What is the difference between *Fluss* and *Strom*, which both translate to *river*?

Comment: "Als Strom wird ein großer Fluss oder ein großes Fließgewässer bezeichnet, das ins Meer mündet. Zu den Charakteristika eines Stromes gehört, dass er mindestens eine Länge von 500 Kilometern hat und mehr als als 2.000 Kubikmeter Wasser pro Sekunde führt." (http://www.wissen.de/raetsel/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-einem-fluss-und-einem-strom)

Comment: "Als Strom wird in gehobener Umgangssprache ein großer Fluss bezeichnet, der ins offene Meer mündet. Als Kriterium wird eine Länge von mindestens 500 km und ein Einzugsgebiet von mindestens 100.000 km² angegeben." (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strom_(Gew%C3%A4sser))

Comment: @hellcode Zwei gut bequellte Zitate reichen Dir nicht, um eine richtige Antwort zu schreiben?

Comment: **To close voters:** Note that the alleged duplicate is in German, and that we have [a policy](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei) not to consider different-language questions duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 3):

The distinction is quite easy. In German, you usually say *Fluss* to any kind of river, so that’d be a proper translation. A small river is called a *Bach*, which in English is called a “stream”, mind you.

A *Strom* (“main stem”, “major river” and others in English; literally “current” or “stream”) however is a larger body of water, usually the **main stream that leads to the open sea** (unlike its tributaries).

Rivers like the Rhine, Ganges and Nile would be called a *Strom* in German, but it’s probably a hydrology term rather than a colloquial one (Wikipedia likes to differ). That being said, there are some criteria to determine when a *Fluss* is called a *Strom* (like the amount of water it conveys or it having an estuary).

Comment: The Rhine can be called _Fluß_, too, and this would be perfectly fine. It is true, though, that one would not call a very small river _Strom_. Then there are other differences:  e g in poems you might more often find _Strom_ than in colloquial speech. And then, both words have different and distinct meanings in other contexts, for example in electricity.

Comment: @MartinPeters: Like I said, you can say *Fluss* (with *ss*, not *ß*) to any *Strom* in German. It’s a good remark on poetry. And naturally, due to their properties of “flow”, there’s some overlap between hydrology and electricity, the former having been invented first.

Comment: @dakab _Fluß_ is the pre-1996 spelling, still used by some people.

Comment: @JDF, I don’t need to be told, as I pointed that out myself—you need to tell the recipient of my comment. Anyhow, that spelling is blatantly wrong, and people who use it commit a spelling mistake, as »Fluß« is no alternative (i.e. tolerated) spelling.

Comment: @dakab It was directed to you. It is not “wrong” since the spelling reforms are not binding on the ordinary population. I happily write my “daß”s and “häßlich”, and indeed “Fluß”s with eszetts, no matter what some officious bureaucrats ordain.

Comment: @JDF, that is a fallacy. They _are_ wrong. Will any German teacher not mark „Fluß“ as a mistake? I am the ẞ’s biggest lover, but those are the rules which constitute the current norm. You can “happily” oppose any rules; that does not apply for the “ordinary population”.

Answer (score 1):

While there is a pretty good agreement on what can be called *Fluss* and what must be called *Bach* (the latter is typically only valid if you can hop across it), there is no clear-cut distinction between a *Fluss* and a *Strom*.

Every larger body of flowing water can be called a *Fluss* (but not a *Bach*) but many would raise an eyebrow if you called them *Strom*. Nowadays — and especially for me — the distinction is typically only size: Somewhere between the size of the Isar in Munich (a *Fluss*) and the Inn and Danube in Passau (*Strom*) is where I would place the absolute lower boundary.

There is also, traditionally, the distinction that a *Strom* had to have some cultural significance for the people living around it, much like the Rhine has for most of western Germany. However, I personally find that argument a bad and neglectable one.